# Page Rank Formula for dead end

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I am trying to understand [this](https://snap.stanford.edu/class/cs224w-2016/slides/page_rank.pdf), especially the last page. For calculating the Page Rank we can use the following formula for matrices:

$$
A = \beta M + (1 - \beta) \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)_{n \times n}    \quad \quad \quad \quad (1)
$$

Then we can use power iteration for the page ranks $r$: $r = Ar$. In order to deal with dead end, columns with only zeros are set to $1/n$.

The Page Rank formula for a single node is defined using:

$$
r_j = \sum_{i\rightarrow j} \beta \frac{r_i}{d_i} + (1 - \beta)\frac{1}{n}     \quad \quad \quad \quad (2)
$$

Can someone explain me how to adapt this formula to deal with dead ends properly?

**Notation**: $\beta$ is a dumping factor between 0 and 1, normally 0.85. $i$ and $j$ are nodes where $i \rightarrow j $ indicates, that there is a edge from $i$ to $j$. $M$ is a weighted Adjacencematrix. $n$ is the number of nodes and $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)_{n \times n}$ indicates a $n \times n$ matrix, where all entries are $1 / n$. $d_i$ is the outdegree of node $i$ and consequently $r_i$ is the pagerank of node $i$. Finally: By dead end I mean a node with outdegree equal to zero.

**My questions**: I assume the first formula can be used for graphs with dead ends, because the columns of dead end nodes in $A$ should be $1/n$ after normalization and there should not be any zeros in the matrix at all. Is that right?

The second formula should not work with dead ends. Is there an easy way to adapt it to work with dead ends, too? I tried something and I think this should be the correct adaption ($D$ denotates the set of all dead end nodes):

$$
r_j = \sum_{i\rightarrow j} \beta \frac{r_i}{d_i} + \sum_{i\in D} \beta \frac{r_i}{n} + (1 - \beta)\frac{1}{n}     \quad \quad \quad \quad (3)
$$

Comment: Since formula $(1)$ works for dead ends, why not simply derive the value of $r_j$ from there?

Comment: Can you explain how formula $(2)$ is different from $(1)$?

Comment: @Pseudonym The first formula will give $$r_j = \sum_{i\rightarrow j} \Big( \frac{\beta}{d_i} + (1 - \beta)\frac{1}{n} \Big)r_i + \sum_{i: (i,j) \notin E } \Big( (1 - \beta)\frac{1}{n} \Big)r_i$$

Comment: Because I wanted a formula, that does not depend on matrices :D